# Why do I lose data stored in an array, which is a field of an object when I try to access it by

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

this has really bugged me. I have an array of objects. The objects have string arrays within them and a string based on this interface

```
export interface Subscription {
  uid: string;
  books: Array<string>;
}
```

the issue is that when I pull my data from firebase's firestore, I would get an empty string when I try to access the books array.

The array returns empty but the string stays intact, when I use array.find to get the specific object I want to use.

Here is my code in my ngOnInit block

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.afAuth.currentUser.then((account) => {
      this.userId = account.uid;
    });
    this.booksService.subs.subscribe((subbed) => {
      this.subscribers = subbed;
      console.log(this.subscribers);
      const subscriberInfo = this.subscribers.find(
        (sub) => sub.uid === this.userId
      );
      console.log(subscriberInfo);
    });
}
```

I pull the data from firebase and the whole array of objects logs in the console with the values intact. I lose the values when trying to find the one object I need.

Comment: Because you are trying to do two asynchronous things at once. It is not gunaranteed that `this.afAuth.currentUser.then` will return before `(sub) => sub.uid === this.userId` uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what @epascarello said.

Try something like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.afAuth.currentUser.then((account) => {
         this.userId = account.uid;
         this.booksService.subs.subscribe((subbed) => {
             this.subscribers = subbed;
             console.log(this.subscribers);
             const subscriberInfo = this.subscribers.find(
                 (sub) => sub.uid === this.userId
             );
             console.log(subscriberInfo);
        });
    });
}
```